# HTTP header construction

Tags: html, http

Given 2 links:

```
<a href="/somepage.html">link1</a>
<a href="somepage.html">link1</a>
```

On a page at this domain:

> **www.site.com/index.html.**

Are both the header request going to look the same ? Or can i expect a **"/somepage.html" and "somepage.html"** request to the site.com domain ?

EDIT: Here is what i see in the raw header in Chrome console:

```
GET /resources/css/jquery-ui.css HTTP/1.1
Host: site.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Referer: http://site.com/
```

So to clarify the question is the request parsed by rewrite engines only the first line?  If so i can use `^/resource` for instance to target it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both will look the same.  `/somepage.html`

The browser creates `/somepage.html`, knowing that it is relative to the current document which is in `/`.  The browser always requests the full path from the server.  This is required, as the server doesn't know what page the browser is currently on.  HTTP is inherently stateless.

Comment: So then what part of the header get parsed by the server when using a rewrite function like Nginx's one? When i inspect the headers source i see: c.f updated Post for clarity

Comment: @silkAdmin, Your edit makes your question an entirely new question...  Can you post it as a new one instead?